# Generate Program whith Pretty Printer Automatically

Tags: abap, pretty-print

I've generated a program via `INSERT REPORT ...`.

I would like to know if there is way to apply the Pretty Printer tool on this program automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basis 7.50:

On pretty printing the ABAP editor calls `pg_pretty_print` FORM in program `LLOCAL_EDT1F08`. It calls the `format_source` method of `cl_sedi_pretty_printer` which runs the FM `PRETTY_PRINTER` inside it.

Basis 7.40 and before:

On pretty printing the ABAP editor calls `pg_pretty_print` FORM in program `LLOCAL_EDT1F08`. It calls the FM `PRETTY_PRINTER` inside it.

The common thing is `PRETTY_PRINTER`. If you debug it and you check the parameters, you can see that `otext` (old source) goes in `ntext` (pretty printed) comes out. So you can pretty print the source code before saving it.